# Audio stream modulation in a browser

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, client-side, webassembly

I am trying to create a calling app that uses WebRTC and a feature I want to add is audio obfuscation.

I want the ability to change the audio pitch that I am sending either at the source audio or even at the receiving end.

I have tried various famous libraries like `P5.js` but still was unable to get the result.

Need some suggestions/sample code in which I can modulate real time audio or even simulate the feeling that I am modulating the real time pitch of the audio.

I would prefer javascript as it will be rendered on the client but I am even open to using some alternative like WebAssembly if that will help me do the job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen this? https://dzone.com/articles/break-free-of-the-realtime-jail-creating-audio-mod

Comment: Thanks @Tschallacka, this looks like a neat solution. I will have a look at this. The only concern I have as of now is not understanding the "Mathy" part, but it should hopefully work out if I put in enough effort.